# Would Schema.org 'Comment' be indexed by Google?

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org

I'm considering to output comments on my blog post as [Schema.org Comments](https://schema.org/Comment).

Google doesn't seem to list `Comment` in their structured data documentation, and more specifically doesn't mention it on the [Article page](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#non-amp) either.

If I add comments via `comment` property on [`CreativeWork`](https://schema.org/CreativeWork) would this be indexed by Google?

Comment: What do you mean by indexed in the context? The typical meaning of *indexing* is that a search engine adds a page it crawled to its database so that it can be part of search results. -- But whether or not you use Schema.org, it wouldn’t affect the indexing.

Comment: @unor by indexing the Comment I specifically mean if someone were to search and the search engine matches the search query with a Comment on my blog post. For that to be possible the comment will have to be in the Search Engines index.
So would the JSON-LD Comment information be indexed in that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schema.org markup doesn't influence on whether your content would be indexed or not. It is only the quality, relevance and importance of your content to certain topic, which plays any role in indexing.

Under no circumstances Schema.org markup, microdata or JSON-LD, will make the content indexable.

However you can use Schema.org markup to make your content better machine-readable.

Comment: But would it be considered part of the content and therefore be searchable upon?

Comment: I guess what I should've asked is whether the JSON-LD shows up in SERP. This page explains that it doesn't: https://centrical.com/test/google-json-ld-and-javascript-crawling-and-indexing-test.html

Comment: Structured Data supports what is visible on the page. Your comments will already be indexed, the structured data may help Google understand that they are comments.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath that answers my question, thanks :)
The comments are added asynchronously using JavaScript which doesn't index that well, that's why I was looking at JSON-LD as an alternative. I'll need to somehow serverside render those comments so they are indexable without needing to run JS.

Comment: Google may pick up those comments. In the search console you can test a URL and then view a preview. That may show if your comments are seen. Or search for a specific comment to see if the page shows up.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to know whether your structured data will be available in the **[rich results of Google](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2017/12/rich-results-tester.html)**.

This may depend on whether Google has support for the main type of your structured data. To determine this, check **[all currently supported Google types of structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery)**.